# Express - Can't send redirect, Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, routes, cors

When trying to redirect the user to the login page, I always get this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

On my express application, I already implemented CORS:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin:  'http://localhost:4200',
  credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Then I try to redirect the user:

```
router.use(function(req,res,next){
    if((req.session.user == null){
        res.redirect('http://localhost:4200' + '/login')
    }
    else
        next();
});
```

On Angular 4 I'm sending all requests with {withCredentials : true}, because I'm using cookies;

These are the request/response headers:

Response:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
>   Connection:keep-alive Date:Thu, 10 Aug 2017 12:09:55 GMT
>   Location:http://localhost:4200/login
>   set-cookie:semanaintegrada.session=s%3A6nieAv1pfn2V-2x7H4HbnqJFbYsgJmwy.hO1QKm%2Fgm6Kmso8pLCQ5zrZAVNhIYgfr%2BgzOB0oI9UA;
>   Path=/; Expires=Thu, 10 Aug 2017 13:09:55 GMT
>   Transfer-Encoding:chunked Vary:Origin X-Powered-By:Express

Request:

> Accept:application/json, text/plain, / Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate,
>   br Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Cache-Control:no-cache Connection:keep-alive Content-Length:39
>   content-type:application/json
>   Cookie:semanaintegrada.session=s%3AwuiVwYs3Ahs4dfLULfpqMBcrnbthY7sZ.OYZk%2FCnZGHAe8v1T8nWpbAdFQVsXjUFAQxnYI27%2FZlE
>   Host:localhost:3000 Origin:http://localhost:4200 Pragma:no-cache
>   Referer:http://localhost:4200/ User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36

Also, in Chrome there are 4 requests that are created ( I dont know why ).
3 to my express app
and 1 to localhost:4200
The last one have Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* and Origin null
Could this be related?

Answer (score 1):

**"credentials flag"** refers to **XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials** of the request being made, not to an Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.

If the request's **withCredentials** is **true**, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` can't be used, even if there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.`

Comment: But I still need to send the 'withCredentials' parameter, because I need to use the cookies in my request, what can I do?